# cakephp 3.0 Acl controller are null

Tags: cakephp, acl

I am trying to call AclComponent function and check the given controller is have permissions 
with the DB record it should have permissions but check function return false

```
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Cake\Controller\ComponentRegistry;
use Acl\Controller\Component\AclComponent;
use Cake\Core\Configure;
$registry = new ComponentRegistry();
$acl = new AclComponent($registry);
debug($acl->check(array('model' => 'User', 'foreign_key' => $_SESSION['Auth']['User']['id']), 'Houses/index'));die();
```

Registry Array :

```
object(Cake\Controller\ComponentRegistry) {

    '_Controller' => null,
    '_loaded' => [],
    '_eventManager' => null,
    '_eventClass' => '\Cake\Event\Event'

}
```

Comment: Code :
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Cake\Controller\ComponentRegistry;
use Acl\Controller\Component\AclComponent;
use Cake\Core\Configure;
    $registry = new ComponentRegistry();
    acl = new AclComponent($registry, Configure::read('Acl'));
    debug($acl->check(array('model' => 'User', 'foreign_key'$_SESSION['Auth']['User']['id']), 'Houses/index'));

Comment: You've accidentally written part of your question in a comment.

Comment: yes  no one answered yet :(